# неизвестный герой (unsung hero)

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

для знака [`неизвестный герой`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero), мне кажется, выбран не самый подходящий перевод.

больше подходит, на мой взгляд, буквальный перевод с английского:

```
unsung hero → невоспетый герой
```

---

также в описании присутствует неоднозначность, несколько сбивающая, по-моему, с толку (выделено мною):

> Нулевой рейтинг принятых ответов, **более 10 и 25%** от общего количества

как переформулировать, пока нет идей, но отталкиваться надо от алгоритма вычисления, который понятен из [этого запроса](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i):

1. как минимум 10 ваших ответов должны быть *приняты* (оно же: «отмечены „галочкой“», оно же «accepted answer») авторами вопросов, **но** не отмечены этими же авторами как *полезные* (оно же: «голос „за“», оно же: «scored answer») (например, по причине: «у автора вопроса меньше 15 баллов репутации»).
2. и количество **таких** ответов должно составлять как минимум 25% от количества **всех** ваших ответов.

---

**обновление**

добавил предложенные (и существующий) варианты в виде ответов.

---

**обновление2**

кстати, есть ещё и связанный с обсуждаемым *серебрянный* знак: [`цепкий`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) (те же критерии, но чуть более «мягкие»: всего 5 (а не 10) *таких* ответов и всего 20% (а не 25%) от всех ответов).

---

**обновление3**

если продолжить аналогию с «предыдущим по табелю о рангах» знаком [`цепкий`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious), то можно, например, использовать слово «стойкий». добавил в варианты.

Comment: Неизвестные герои всегда идут в обход. В обход обсуждения знаков которое было при локализации 3 месяца назад.

Comment: @igumnov, спасибо за информацию, но поиск как слова *unsung*, так и слова *неизвестный*, дают лишь один результат: вот этот самый мой вопрос. возможно, я не там ищу?

Comment: [Вот это например](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Безымянные_герои) и [английская версия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsung_Heroes). А то что вы предлагаете это машинный перевод же.

Comment: @igumnov, хороший вариант. жаль только, что он, по-моему, не соответствует смыслу обсуждаемого знака. а прокатные названия иностранным фильмам (он иностранный как для американского, так и для российского прокатов) дают, порою, весьма далёкие от задумки авторов. но это, конечно, мало относится к обсуждаемому знаку.

Comment: Я не знаток английского, но по смыслу д.б. что-то вроде `недооцененный герой` (звучит, конечно, не очень...)

Comment: `Скромный герой`?

Comment: А ещё вариант из киноклассики: `Деточкин`.

Comment: @VladD, ну, «деточкин» — это, по-моему уже перебор, то ли с сарказмом, то ли с иронией. к тому же, молодёжь может просто не понять, о чём речь.

Comment: Ну это да. Просто хотелось сослаться на какой-нибудь культурный феномен.

Comment: @VladD, так добавьте в виде ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Этот вариант мне не очень нравится. Если будет что-нибудь достойное — обязательно добавлю.

Comment: @VladD, если нужен фольклор, то, подключив фантазию, можно много напридумывать: `награда нашла героя`, `боец невидимого фронта`, `две недали` и т.д.

Comment: Хм. Награда нашла героя мне кажется хуже, потому что тут как бы не «заслуженные баллы», а «значок в утешение». А вот «боец невидимого фронта» мне нравится.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Как мне кажется, можно отметить выбранный вариант правильным.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, «для отчётности»? отметил принятым вариант, набравший больше всего голосов — «непризнанный гений».

Comment: Для удобства. 1) Чтобы все знали используемый вариант, 2) я время от времени просматриваю все не принятые ответы.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Нашел тут вариант "непризнанный гений" - по-моему, вполне подходит под описание медали.

Comment: По-моему, неплохо.

Comment: Отличный вариант! Тогда вместо [«цепкий»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) — «скрытый талант», например.

Comment: Позволил себе внести вариант в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262462?q=tenacious). // CC @Nicolas

Answer (score 9):

**вариант**

«невоспетый герой»

Answer (score 9):

**вариант**

«боец невидимого фронта»

Answer (score 3):

[Tenacious](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) — [Скрытый талант](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/754/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-unsung-hero?cb=1#comment2410_804)

Только в паре с [Непризнанным Гением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/804/181472)

Answer (score 2):

**вариант**

оставить «неизвестный герой»

Answer (score 2):

**вариант**

«недооцененный герой»

Answer (score 1):

**вариант**

«скромный герой»

Answer (score 1):

**вариант**

«стойкий» (в продолжение идеи «предыдущего по табели о рангах» знака [`цепкий`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious))

Answer (score -1):

**вариант**

«безымянный герой»